# Importing data as dynamically as possible

Tags: scala, etl

Im looking for some mini pattern:
The program should be able to support various formats as Input and then apply a transformation and in the last step load them into a database.

Its main purpose is to provide test data.

My initial idea was to "glue" different components together like this:

We have an extractor that extracts from a generic datasource [A] to an iterator of [B]
and then a transformator that maps [B] to  [C] and finally a step that loads [C] into a database. I'm sure there must be a better way of approaching this. Is there a better , possibly more generic way of achieving this?

```
trait Importer[A, B, C] {

  val extractor: Extractor[A, B]
  val transformer: Transformator[B, C]
  val loader: Loader[C]

  /**
   * this is the method call for chaining all events together
   */
  def importAndTransformData(dataSource: A): Unit =
    {
     /**
      * extraction step
      */
      val output = extractor.extract(dataSource: A)

      /**
       * conversion method
       */
      val transformed = output map (transformer.transform(_))

      /**
       * loading step
       */
      transformed.foreach(loader.load(_))
    }

}
```

with best regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common approach used in Scala is self-typing (especially as used in the [Cake Pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/t_rapw)). In your case that would look something like:

```
trait Importer[A, B, C] {
  self: Extractor[A, B] with Transformator[B, C] with Loader[C] =>

  /**
   * this is the method call for chaining all events together
   */
  def importAndTransformData(dataSource: A): Unit =
    {
     /**
      * extraction step
      */
      val output = extract(dataSource: A)

      /**
       * conversion method
       */
      val transformed = output map (transform(_))

      /**
       * loading step
       */
      transformed.foreach(load(_))
    }

}
```

You can then build your Importer with code such as:

```
val importer = new Importer with FooExtractor with FooBarTransformer with BarLoader {}
```

or

```
val testImporter = Importer with MockExtractor with TestTransformer with MockLoader {}
```

or similar for your test cases.

Comment: thanks for your input. my main concern tho was regarding the dynamic fashion of the importing process. if there is an approach of elegantly handling dynamic data structures in a generic fashion whether it may be Databases,FlatFiles,XmlFiles or Binarystreams